# Change HTML code of GridView filter in Yii Framework

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have a GridView. It generates a filter for this table.

```
<tr id="w0-filters" class="filters">
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="someId" name="someName" value="aaa">
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I would need this output, note the added link next to the input:

```
<td>
    <input...>
    <a href="#">Something</a>
</td>
```

Comment: You want use the filter like an url?

Comment: I want to make a link which you can reset (delete) the filter with. I just want users have a possibility to quick reset the filter...